# How to print OKAY if required variables are not empty?

Tags: python

```
a='1'
b='Apple'
c='Banana'

d='Some thing'
e=''
f=''
if (a and b and c !='') or (d and e and f !=''):
    print("OKAY")
else:
    print("Not OKAY")
```

As of my example code it is printing okay. But it should be print Okay either both d,e and f are should be empty or both should not to be empty. For example if  a,b and c are not empty and d,e and f are empty then it should be print "okay". And a, b, c are not empty and d is not empty, e and f are empty so in this case it should print "not OKAY". Or if ab and c are not empty and d, e and f are also not empty then it should be print "OKAY". How to do. I don't have an practical idea that's why i could  not given an example.

Truth Table:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your condition is that all items in a group need to be the same, empty or non-empty, and at least one of the two groups needs to be all non-empty. So you could say that each group has a ternary state: `True` (all non-empty), `False` (all empty) or `None` (mixed emptiness):

```
def group_state(*args):
    result = set(map(bool, args))
    if len(result) > 1:
        return None  # mixed truthiness
    return result.pop()  # one True or False value
```

Then you would have a comparison like:

```
if group_state(a, b, c) is not None and group_state(d, e, f) is not None \
        and (group_state(a, b, c) or group_state(d, e, f)):
    ...
```

Which we can write a little more elegantly as:

```
try:
    result = sum((group_state(a, b, c), group_state(d, e, f))) >= 1
except TypeError:
    result = False

if result:
    ...
```

We're taking advantage of the fact that `True` behaves as `1`, `False` behaves as `0`, and `None` cannot be summed up and results in a `TypeError`. So if either group results in `None`, it'll raise a `TypeError` and the end result is `False`. Otherwise, we'll want at least one group to be truthy, i.e. the `sum` needs to be at least `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    if all((a, b, c)):
        if not any((d, e, f)):
            return 'Okay'
    if all((d, e, f)):
        if not any((a, b, c)):
            return 'Okay'
    if all((a, b, c, d, e, f)):
        return 'Okay'
    return 'Not Okay'
```

- `any()` returns True if any of `a`, `b` or `c` have text
- `all()` returns True if all of `a`, `b` and `c` have text

-------- **TESTS** --------

```
a = 'text'
b = 'text'
c = ''
d = ''
e = ''
f = ''

>> Not Okay

a = 'text'
b = 'text'
c = 'text'
d = ''
e = ''
f = ''

>> Okay

a = 'text'
b = 'text'
c = 'text'
d = 'text'
e = 'text'
f = 'text' 

>> Okay

a = ''
b = ''
c = ''
d = 'text'
e = 'text'
f = 'text'

>> Okay

a = ''
b = ''
c = ''
d = ''
e = ''
f = ''

>> Not Okay

a = 'text'
b = 'text'
c = 'text'
d = 'text'
e = ''
f = ''

>> Not Okay
```

Comment: How Can i use your function in my example code?

Comment: Set variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` then pass them as arguments into the function. Finally write `print(func(a, b, c, d, e, f))`